# My tv screen goes black and back on when i open the door

Tags: doors, switch, television

I moved into a house and i noticed that whenever anyone opens the outside door my tv screen goes black and back on couple times. I have laptop connected to tv. Nothing else is affected but the tv. Bought new tv after a while and still same problem. Checked the door but it is just regular door. No alarms or doorbells connected. Anyone has any thoughts?

Comment: Could opening the door cause vibrations that are affecting the TV power cord?

Comment: loose wiring in the power outlet maybe. ... put the tv on an extension cord and plug in someplace else.

Comment: does the sound cut out or just the picture?

Comment: The door opening could jiggle a loose wire in the stab back switches located by the front door that control that outlet.

Comment: Update: Found the problem. The door, that affects tv, leads to garage. In the garage i have one of those flouresent lights. And that is what affects my tv. Every time anyone opens the door they flick the light switch on and thats why i thought it is the door that messes everything up. Took the starter out of the light and everything went back to normal!